# Nginx add modules = how to?

Tags: nginx, oraclelinux

I just install Nginx on Oracle linux and working with it as reverse proxy.

it's wroking as I wanted.

now I want to add this moudle:

> ngx_http_v2_module

how do I do this ?
where is the config file ?

everywhere I looked they say

> his module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_v2_module configuration parameter.

but I don't see any example of how to do it ....

when I enter

/usr/share/nginx/moudles/

I see this files only :

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 65 Mar 30  2018 mod-http-geoip.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 72 Mar 30  2018 mod-http-image-filter.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 64 Mar 30  2018 mod-http-perl.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 71 Mar 30  2018 mod-http-xslt-filter.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 59 Mar 30  2018 mod-mail.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 61 Mar 30  2018 mod-stream.conf
```

so do I need to download something ? and put it in this directory ?

also 
with this module I could push image to user? 
meaning he will go the websites and will see my image\icon in his webpage?
or do I need another module ?

Thanks,

Comment: When I run the command I see I have (--with-http_v2_module) , now what?

Comment: Ok , how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is about Oracle Linux 7, Oracle provides nginx in two channels:

- EPEL packages for Oracle Linux 7 (ol7_developer_EPEL)

```
 # yum info nginx
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Installed Packages
Name        : nginx
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.12.2
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 1.5 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : ol7_developer_EPEL
Summary     : A high performance web server and reverse proxy server
URL         : http://nginx.org/
License     : BSD
Description : Nginx is a web server and a reverse proxy server for HTTP, SMTP, POP3 and
            : IMAP protocols, with a strong focus on high concurrency, performance and low
            : memory usage.
```

and it is compiled with the http2 module:

```
# /usr/sbin/nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -e 's/--with/\n\0/g' | grep http_v2
--with-http_v2_module
```

- Alternatively there is also a version in the Software Collection Library (ol7_software_collections)

```
# yum info rh-nginx114
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Installed Packages
Name        : rh-nginx114
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.14
Release     : 6.el7
Size        : 0.0  
Repo        : installed
From repo   : ol7_software_collections
Summary     : Package that installs rh-nginx114
License     : GPLv2+
Description : This is the main package for rh-nginx114 Software Collection.
```

where we also have support for http2:

```
# /opt/rh/rh-nginx114/root/usr/sbin/nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -e 's/--with/\n\0/g' | grep http_v2
--with-http_v2_module
```

So basically whatever version you have installed, you should be covered.

For the configuration of this module, you should look at the [upstream NGINX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html).

Comment: I check and I have like you post in the first one :   EPEL packages for Oracle Linux 7.   but what do I need to in order to make it work , what to change in the config file?

Comment: also waht to know - what I need to do in order to add a simple jpg bunner in every web page the user enter from my proxy  -- can this module do this? or I need something else ?

Comment: The http_v2_module supports the HTTP2 protocol, and and its _Server Push_ feature has nothing to do what you are trying to achieve (I'm afraid there is no simple solution for that).

Comment: ohhhh , I thought I can do this . well at least now I know it can't be done - and I will not waste time on it .   Thanks !